# Rails dropdown shows textbox when "other" is selected

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I've created a dropdown form that shows a textbox when the option is "other".  The other option works fine and users can add another option, but if the user selects anything other than the "Other" option the validation fails and says "This can't be blank".

All this is done on the _form.html.erb page here is the HTML and Ruby:

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label 'Escola' %><br>
    <%= f.select(:school, ["FGV", "Other"]) %>
     <%= f.text_field :school, class: "school-show", style: "display: none;"%>

  </div>
```

Here is the jquery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#professor_school').change(function() {
  if(this.value == "Other") {
    $('.school-show').show();
  }else{
    $('.school-show').hide();
  }
});
});
</script>
```

I think the problem is that I have two fields that are trying to put into the column "school" in the database and that's causing the problem, but I may be wrong and I don't know anyway around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is 'best practice' and I am sure there is a better way, but what I would do is set the value of the text field every time the drop down changes. So something like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#professor_school').change(function() {
    if(this.value == "Other") {
      $('.school-show').val('');      
      $('.school-show').show();
    }else{
      $('.school-show').val(this.value);
      $('.school-show').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

I demonstrated it here https://jsfiddle.net/8os10o8L/, it's plain html but you get the idea. And maybe change the param on the drop down or take it out of the form so you don't run into further issues.

Comment: This only works, for me at least, if I actually change the dropdown, if I enter the page fill out the form but don't change the dropdown at all it doesn't work.

Comment: you can either change the default value of the textfield manually like

Comment: you can either change the default value of the textfield manually like <%= f.text_field :school, value: "FGV" class: "school-show", style: "display: none;"%>

Comment: or you can have jquery set it like $(document).ready(function(){$('.school-show').val($('#professor_school').value)});

Comment: Hmm I can't get that jquery solution to work but I got the text field manual thing to work.  It's ugly but it'll do for now, thanks.